# im trying to make a discord bot with discord.js and my command doesnt seem to be working even if i get no errors, how do i fix?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

im still a bit new to javascript, i started by following a tutorial i found on youtube, and that didnt seem to work, dug a bit deeper and a few more errors later, it still doesnt work.
my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const prefix = require('discord-prefix');

prefix.setPrefix('b.');

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
})

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
  if(message.content === "help") {
    message.channel.send("nah");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token)
```

i can confirm that the token is correct, so i dont think the issue stems from there.

Answer (score 0):

In your messageCreate event handler, you're `return`ing on messages that don't start with the bot prefix. But what the statement afterward is looking for is a message that contains just the word `help`, which doesn't start with the prefix of `b.`

What you are trying to detect would be `b.help`, so you'd do that with (this is a guess based on `discord-prefix`'s NPM entry):

```
// ...

if (message.content.startsWith(prefix.getPrefix(message.guild.id) + "help")) {
    // ...
}
```

I've rewritten your code with that change below.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const prefix = require('discord-prefix');

prefix.setPrefix('b.');

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Project is running!");
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
})

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix.getPrefix(message.guild.id) + "help")) {
    message.channel.send("nah");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.token)
```